# Stopping application from not displaying because of form_load code

Tags: c#

How can I stop my application from not displaying until the form_load code is completed?

```
public partial class updater : Form
{
    public updater()
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = (10000) * (1);
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar1.Update();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void updater_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += webClient_DownloadProgressChanged;

        webClient.DownloadFile("http://download827.mediafire.com/jl9c098fnedg/ncqun56uddq0y1d/Stephen+Swartz+-+Survivor+%28Feat+Chloe+Angelides%29.wav", Application.StartupPath + "\\Stephen Swartz - Survivor (Feat Chloe Angelides).wav");
        // System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("\\Test.exe");
        this.Close();   
    }
    void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressBar1.Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: use the `Shown` event not the `Load` event.

Comment: Please restate the question without the double-negative. No idea what you want to accomplish here.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `DownloadFileAsync` it wont block the UI thread and will allow the `Form` to load and show the progress in the `Progressbar`, then you can use the `DownloadFileCompleted` event to close the `Form`

Example:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar1.Update();
    }

    private void updater_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += webClient_DownloadProgressChanged;
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://download827.mediafire.com/jl9c098fnedg/ncqun56uddq0y1d/Stephen+Swartz+-+Survivor+%28Feat+Chloe+Angelides%29.wav"), Application.StartupPath + "\\Stephen Swartz - Survivor (Feat Chloe Angelides).wav");
    }

    private void webClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }

    private void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        progressBar1.Update();
    }
```

Comment: This works! I tried the form_show method, but it didn't work so I decided to try this! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to move your code from Load [Shown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx). So the code will start runing after the form is shown.

The other is create a [thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), where you will download a file.
For this purpose you can use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

```
private void updater_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (s, eArgs) =>
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFile("someUrl", "somePath");
        };
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

---

Also there exists `webClient.DownloadFileAsync` method witch suits better in this situation. You can find description in sa_ddam213 answer.